# Remove a row using Google Scripts will break a reference in another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I got this Google Sheets project which works like following:

1. Someone creates a new sheet with an unique ID
2. This sheet will be saved in the database sheet, with all corresponding data.
3. When the sheet is completed, it will be closed. When it's being closed, the script will look up the database row and take the data, and paste it in the closed-database. The row in the normal database where this sheet was present, will be deleted.

Now there's the following problem:

For another function, the data from the normal database will be imported in another sheet, where it'll filter the unique IDs. It's referenced as `=DB!A2` etc, but when the row is deleted at the end of step 3, the reference will stop working.

E.g. when row 5 in the database is deleted, `=DB!A5` and `=DB!R5` will be deleted from the other sheet, and will display `#REF`.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the value obtained by referencing `=DB!A5` after the cell A5 in sheet DB is deleted, it's necessary to replace this formula by that value. For example, if this formula is in cell A1 of Sheet1, the following will do the job.

```
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1");
cell.copyTo(cell, {contentsOnly: true});
```

The important part here is that the cell is copied to itself with the option of preserving only the content (not the formula). This is equivalent to pressing Ctrl-C and then Ctrl-Shift-V on the same cell.